# MVC Duplicating Drop-Down list on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a page where the user selects an item in a drop-down list, which then will create a duplicate drop-down list.  The last drop-down list always needs to create a new one once an item is selected.

Using the following javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(function listselect() {            
        if (x == null) {
            var x = 1;
        }

        //need to increment x after the completion of the following funciton so the function will trigger on different drop-down lists

            $('#FooId' + x).change(function q() {
                $('#FooId' + x).clone().attr('id', 'FooId' + (++x)).attr('name', 'Selected').insertAfter('#FooId' + (x - 1))
                //return x;
            });
            //return x;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the razor html

```
<div class ="container">
        <div class="label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Foo, "Foo")
        </div>
        <div class="foo" id="foo">
            @Html.DropDownList("FooId", Nothing, "--Select--", New With {.Name = "Selected", .Id = "FooId" & "1"})
            //@*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Foo)*@

        </div>
    </div>
```

I am able to make the first list clone itself, but how do you return x from function q so that it can be used by its own function (Function q needs to trigger when an item is selected in Foo1, then Foo2, etc.).

(Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am not sure how to word it.  I am very new to coding).  Thanks.

Comment: With the new lists, do you need a new row with a label and a container? Or do you have just one label and then lots of drop downs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you don't need most of your code. And it's easier to use classes here. Just do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.foo').on('change', function(e) {
        var newFoo = $(e.target).clone();
        $(e.target).after(newFoo);
    });
});
```

And your markup part should be like this:

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Foo, "Foo")
    </div>
    <div class="foo" id="foo">
        @Html.DropDownList("FooId", Nothing, "--Select--", new {name = "Selected", @class = "foo" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't remember Html.DropDownList signature so I created simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5axR/) without it. I hope this is what you needed.

#### UPDATE:

I've corrected my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5axR/4/) as follows:

```
$(document).on('change', '.foo:last', function(e) {
    var newFoo = $(e.target).clone();
    $(e.target).after(newFoo);
});
```

Now it doesn't add extra selects if it's not the last select that was changed.

Comment: Thanks.  That is close to what I need and helps a lot.  The only thing is that only the last select list should create a clone.  (Ex. List 1 creates List 2, List 2 can create List 3, but list 1 no longer will create any list)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I also added .attr('id', 'FooId' + (++x)) after .clone() to give each select list a unique id.  (I have to turn them into comboboxes yet, so I need unique ids).  Thanks for the help!